# How to use JSONP

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain, jsonp

I have the following code

```
function exista(word) {
    alert(word);
    var exists = 1;
    jQuery.ajax({
        async: false, 
        url: "http://api.wordreference.com/0.8/key/json/roen/" + word,
        dataType: 'json',
        method: "GET",
        success: function(transport) {
            if (transport.Error || transport.Response)
                exists = 0;
        }

    });
    return exists;
}
```

which verifies if a word exists or not in a dictionary. Problem is it gives an Access-Control-Allow-Origin error. From what I gathered it seems I must use JSONP but I can't really figure out how (sorry, I am just beginning to learn JavaScript and all that). So, got any idea on how to modify the above code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Your `dataType` should be `jsonp`, not 'json`.

**UPDATE**

According to http://www.wordreference.com/docs/api.aspx:

> Additionally, for JSPONp, the JSON API can take an optional callback
>   function in the query string; simply add "?callback={yourCallback}" to
>   the end of the URL.

so the API does support JSONP.

Additionally, JSONP means "JSON with padding", so you will get a JSON response. JSONP merely allows use of [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

By changing your [`dataType`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to `jsonp`:

> "jsonp": Loads in a JSON block using JSONP. Adds an extra
>   "?callback=?" to the end of your URL to specify the callback. Disables
>   caching by appending a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the
>   URL unless the cache option is set to true.

You can override the default callback by specifying one with the `jsonpCallback` setting.

Finally, you should also add an error handler and set `async` to `true`:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    "async": true, //cannot be false for JSONP
    "url": "http://api.wordreference.com/0.8/key/json/roen/" + word,
    "dataType": 'jsonp',
    "method": "GET",
    "error": function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //included so you can see any errors
        console.log(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
    },
    "success": function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        //According to API documentation
        //data will not likely contain either Error, or Response
        //so, exists will likely not change to 0
        if (data.Error || data.Response) {
            exists = 0;
        }
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:**

The solution to both the error and the "need to be synchronous" is going to be what [Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy) pointed out earlier. You'll have to create a server-side proxy that runs on the same domain as your script.

The server-side proxy can return JSONP, but frankly simply returning JSON or XML is simpler since [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) is not an issue, and the proxy can be synchronous. For a PHP example script, the [Yahoo! Developer Network](http://developer.yahoo.com/) hosts [source code for a simple proxy](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/samples/proxy/php_proxy_simple.txt).

For anything else regarding a server-side web service proxy, you'd need to specify which server language you're using (and it would probably be better suited as a different question).

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. I get this in the console: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://api.wordreference.com/0.8/key/json/roen/SAT?callback=jQuery18307907822206616402_1358093876872&_=1358093891468"

Comment: And I need the response to be synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

For JSONP to work, you not only have to code for it on *your* side, but the site you're targeting has to expect to be used that way as well, and respond to requests accordingly.

If the other site does not have a JSONP API already, and you have no control over it, then JSONP is not an answer. You'll have to create a server-side proxy of your own.

*edit* — according to the site, they do support JSONP.  You just need to add "?callback=?" to the end of the URL.